# Campo JTextField

Tags: java, sql, data

Como converter um componente `JTextField` para tipo `Date`? Como fazer pesquisar?
Como criar um consulta para o banco  retornando uma lista dos pedidos de  acordo com um intervalo de datas?

Segue o código utilizado atualmente:

```
if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Escolha uma Opção de Busca!");
} else if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
   RS = stmt.executeQuery("select numped FROM PCPEDC WHERE DATA > '10/01/2014' and numped =  " + BuscaCodigo);
   while (RS.next()) {
      int Num = RS.getInt("numped");

      consulta = false;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados Encontrado!!!!");
   }
} else if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
   RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Data FROM PCPEDC WHERE Data BETWEEN " + Dtincial + "AND" + Dtfinal);

   while (RS.next()) {
      int Num = RS.getInt("numped");
      //...
   }
}
```

```
//mascara para os campos //
Dtincial = new JFormattedTextField(DateFormat.getDateInstance( ));
try {  
   javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter data= new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
   Dtincial = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(data);        
} catch (Exception e){
}

Dtincial.setColumns(10);
Dtfinal = new JFormattedTextField(DateFormat.getDateInstance( ));
try {  
   javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter data= new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
   Dtfinal  = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(data);        
} catch (Exception e){
}

//declaração dos atributos
private JTextField Dtincial;
private JTextField Dtfinal;
```

Comment: Cara desculpe mais não entendi esse processo, fiz coisa similar a isso é não deu certo

Comment: vou colocar um codigo aqui em cima

Comment: mais no caso na hora de setar a data ele fica dando erro, tipo isso:
ps.setDate(1, Dtincial);
ps.setDate(2, Dtfinal);

Comment: alguém pra ajudar?

Comment: Você está querendo passar um `JFormattedTextField` para um método que recebe uma `Date`, vai dar erro mesmo. Você tem que pegar o **valor** do textfield e não o objeto.

Answer (score 2):

#### `SimpleDateFormat`

Documentação e Patterns: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// Valor no textfield. Entrada: 14/01/2015
String text= textField.getText();

Date date = dateFormat.parse(text);

System.out.println(date.toString); //Wed Jan 14 00:00:00 BRST 2015
System.out.println(date.toInstant().toString()); // 2015-01-14T02:00:00Z
```

---

### `DateFormat`

```
// Entrada: 01/01/2015
String text= textField.getText();
Date date = null;

try {
   date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(text);
} catch (ParseException e){
   // Tratamento de exceção.
}
System.out.println(date.toString()); // Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 BRST 2015
System.out.println(date.toInstant().toString()); // 2015-01-01T02:00:00Z
```

Nessa caso a conversão é feita para o `Date` do pacote `java.util`, se não me engano *Statements* e *PreparedStaments* recebem um objeto `Date` do pacote `java.sql`. Se for isso mesmo, veja [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) no StackOverflow-en.